# Error while compiling the Xcode project (IPhone)

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

I added ffmpeg iphone port into my library and I can able to use a few of its functions like avcodec_init(),.. without any errors.
But when I include this function call "avcodec_register_all" Xcode is giving error after compilation

The error message is :

*---------------
ld: ldr 12-bit displacement out of range (4276 max +/-4096) in _CFRelease$stub in _CFRelease$stub from /Users/foxit/Documents/CameraTest/build/CameraTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/CameraTest.build/Objects-normal/armv6/CameraTest

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

*-------------

Does anyone know whats wrong with this ?

Regards,

Raghu

Answer (score 3):

This problem exists in iPhone OS 3.1 or later while building in Xcode. Try re-arringing the link order of the libraries in your target's link library phase. I have discussed this issue in: http://www.galloway.me.uk/2009/12/ldr-12-bit-displacement-out-of-range/

There is an inherent problem in iPhone SDK 3.1 and later. Will have to wait until Apple fixes it or we will have to do some trail and error changes.

In our case, just re-ordering libavfilter and libavcodec to the last would simply work.

Comment: Hi Raj,
 Do you know a way to convert raw surface buffer to AvFrame() ?
I am trying to write a video recording application.I am able to hold the raw data of the image (screen) but not able to find the conversion from that raw data into AVframe to encode it.
Thanks

Comment: Follow output-example.c file in the source of FFMpeg source. Implement the required methods from it. Override fill_yuv_image() method so that you convert your RGB data to YUV by using sws_scale() method and fill that raw data into AVFrame which is passed as an argument to fill_yuv_image().

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of the error by unselecting the "Compile For Thumb" compiler option.

So here are my settings:

```
Base SDK:  iPhone Device 4.0 
iPhone OS Deployment Target: 3.1.3
```

I did add -no_order_inits to the linker options but that did not work for me.

If you select a deployment target of 3.0 then you also will not get the error.

BTW, I am also using the FFMPEG and libMMS libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Same as 
[this problem?](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/4095/iphone-enable-internal-profiler-doesnt-work)

Suggestion there is:

> Please select deployment target "iPhone OS 3.0" or earlier. It is known Xcode linker issue with deployment targets "iPhone OS 3.1" and later.

Comment: No that is not the problem, the same thing working in another Xocde project which I cant use it for some reasons

Comment: I was also seeing this problem and reordering my frameworks didn't work.  After changing my build target from 3.1 to 3.0 the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

For me on 4.2 and using ffmpeg, solution was to specify "Optimized (armv7)" in field "Architectures" instead "Standard (armv6 armv7)"
if this can help you...

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using a CMake generated XCode project I don't have all the flexibility I would like in re-ordering my link lines.  I stared at the ld(1) man page for a while and found this:

**-no_order_inits**

> "When the -order_file option is not
>   used, the linker lays out functions in
>   object file order and it moves all
>   initializer routines to the start of
>   the __text section and terminator
>   routines to the end. Use this option
>   to disable the automatic
>   re-arrangement of initializers and
>   terminators."

Adding this to the link line made the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in `MonoTouch`, and posted a solution for it here: http://microsoft2apple.com/2010/09/30/solved-ldr-12-bit-displacement-out-of-range/