# Error when release compile with a thrid party library in monotouch

Tags: release, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

#### Update III:

After googling around I've found that this is not an uncommon problem. But I seem not to be able to resolve it. I've tried:

```
"-no_order_inits"
 -v -v -v -gcc_flags "-no_order_inits -L${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone -lCorePlot -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone/libCorePlot.a"
```

I also have tried to set it to "not link". But same problem occurs. Following the pages:

- [Error while compiling the Xcode project (IPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380397/error-while-compiling-the-xcode-project-iphone)
- http://www.galloway.me.uk/2009/12/ldr-12-bit-displacement-out-of-range/
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/4095/iphone-enable-internal-profiler-doesnt-work

#### Update II:

I've removed all (one actually - `_hostingView.Layer.SublayerTransform = CATransform3D.MakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)` ) `CGAffineTransform` from the source files and rebuilt, but same problem exists. I also (in desperation) removed all transforms at all from source but same problem occurs.

Cheers,
 Mario

#### Update:

I'm using the `-v -v -v` (on correct place as well ;) - thanks to geoff and replaced the output with the new more verbose output:

```
"-gcc_flags " -v -v -L${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone -lCorePlot -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone/libCorePlot.a".
```

It seems that this is causing the error, but I have no clue how to fix this:

```
ld: ldr 12-bit displacement out of range (4344 max +/-4096) in _CATransform3DGetAffineTransform$stub in _CATransform3DGetAffineTransform$stub from /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Cheers, 
 Mario

Hi, I've decorated and created a wrapper for coreplot. It works in the simulator debug/release and iPhone (device) debug. But I cannot make it build in iPhone release.  I get the following error while compiling in it release mode (in to native step). Does anyone know why this issiue occurs?

I use the following following extra arguments:

- `iPhoneSimulator|Debug -> -gcc_flags " -L${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhoneSimulator -lCorePlot -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhoneSimulator/libCorePlot.a"` [Works]
- `iPhoneSimulator|Release -> -gcc_flags " -L${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhoneSimulator -lCorePlot -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhoneSimulator/libCorePlot.a"` [Works]
- `iPhone|Debug -> -gcc_flags " -L${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone -lCorePlot -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone/libCorePlot.a"` [Works]
- `iPhone|Release -> -gcc_flags " -v -v -L${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone -lCorePlot -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone/libCorePlot.a"` [Do not work]

I use SDK version: 4.1

Cheers,
  Mario

Output for build (trimmed):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch  -v --nomanifest --nosign -dev "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app"  -r="/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Common/Effect.Core/bin/iPhone/Release/EffectCore.dll" -r="/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r="/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r="/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r="/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -r="/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/libs/CorePlotWrapper.dll" -sdk="4.1" -targetver="3.1.2"  -v -v -v -gcc_flags "-L/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/libs/iPhone -lCorePlot -force_load /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/libs/iPhone/libCorePlot.a" "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/CurrentCost.exe"
Framework is: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk
Copied /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/CurrentCost.exe to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/CurrentCost.exe
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/mscorlib.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/mscorlib.dll
Copied /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Common/Effect.Core/bin/iPhone/Release/EffectCore.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/EffectCore.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/Mono.Security.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Web.Services.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Xml.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Core.dll
Copied /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/monotouch.dll
Copied /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/libs/CorePlotWrapper.dll to /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/CorePlotWrapper.dll
Linking assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/CurrentCost.exe into /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Web.Services.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Web.Services.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Web.Services.dll
Code: 87164 Info: 2095 Ex Info: 2235 Unwind Info: 1957 Class Info: 2628 PLT: 337 GOT Info: 5472 GOT Info Offsets: 2660 GOT: 2664 Offsets: 5112
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Web.Services.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_System_Web_Services_info'.
Compiled 397 out of 397 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 211 (53%)
Direct calls: 71 (36%)
JIT time: 143 ms, Generation time: 72 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/EffectCore.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/EffectCore.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/EffectCore.dll
Code: 68408 Info: 1735 Ex Info: 2523 Unwind Info: 1388 Class Info: 1664 PLT: 245 GOT Info: 6439 GOT Info Offsets: 1844 GOT: 1848 Offsets: 6468
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/EffectCore.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_EffectCore_info'.
Compiled 467 out of 467 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 277 (59%)
Direct calls: 17 (26%)
JIT time: 119 ms, Generation time: 74 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.dll
Code: 552096 Info: 14092 Ex Info: 16283 Unwind Info: 4427 Class Info: 13833 PLT: 1324 GOT Info: 17300 GOT Info Offsets: 10584 GOT: 10588 Offsets: 34464
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_System_info'.
Compiled 2649 out of 2649 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 1512 (57%)
Direct calls: 1312 (43%)
JIT time: 874 ms, Generation time: 493 ms, Assembly+Link time: 79 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/monotouch.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/monotouch.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/monotouch.dll
Code: 237196 Info: 8510 Ex Info: 8393 Unwind Info: 2398 Class Info: 7162 PLT: 731 GOT Info: 15564 GOT Info Offsets: 6516 GOT: 6520 Offsets: 23136
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/monotouch.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_monotouch_info'.
Compiled 1601 out of 1601 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 668 (41%)
Direct calls: 377 (29%)
JIT time: 358 ms, Generation time: 218 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CorePlotWrapper.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/CorePlotWrapper.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/CorePlotWrapper.dll
Code: 213780 Info: 10041 Ex Info: 5673 Unwind Info: 1281 Class Info: 9090 PLT: 247 GOT Info: 7462 GOT Info Offsets: 6444 GOT: 6448 Offsets: 14904
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CorePlotWrapper.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_CorePlotWrapper_info'.
Compiled 1150 out of 1150 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 170 (14%)
Direct calls: 166 (57%)
JIT time: 311 ms, Generation time: 147 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/mscorlib.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/mscorlib.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/mscorlib.dll
Code: 1438420 Info: 36834 Ex Info: 43961 Unwind Info: 5964 Class Info: 24479 PLT: 2341 GOT Info: 57333 GOT Info Offsets: 19752 GOT: 36652 Offsets: 91356
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/mscorlib.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_mscorlib_info'.
Compiled 6743 out of 6743 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 4307 (63%)
Direct calls: 5191 (48%)
JIT time: 1569 ms, Generation time: 872 ms, Assembly+Link time: 353 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Xml.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Xml.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Xml.dll
Code: 903780 Info: 22355 Ex Info: 20643 Unwind Info: 5370 Class Info: 18282 PLT: 1394 GOT Info: 20584 GOT Info Offsets: 14016 GOT: 14020 Offsets: 46332
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Xml.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_System_Xml_info'.
Compiled 3687 out of 3687 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 2215 (60%)
Direct calls: 2620 (43%)
JIT time: 1026 ms, Generation time: 455 ms, Assembly+Link time: 187 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Core.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Core.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/System.Core.dll
Code: 7736 Info: 139 Ex Info: 1698 Unwind Info: 339 Class Info: 233 PLT: 61 GOT Info: 3186 GOT Info Offsets: 328 GOT: 332 Offsets: 708
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Core.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_System_Core_info'.
Compiled 50 out of 50 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 40 (80%)
Direct calls: 15 (62%)
JIT time: 12 ms, Generation time: 19 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/Mono.Security.dll"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/Mono.Security.dll
Code: 247904 Info: 5041 Ex Info: 6559 Unwind Info: 3199 Class Info: 6723 PLT: 534 GOT Info: 7068 GOT Info Offsets: 4240 GOT: 4244 Offsets: 13824
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_Mono_Security_info'.
Compiled 1091 out of 1091 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 616 (56%)
Direct calls: 723 (40%)
JIT time: 299 ms, Generation time: 152 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
MONO_PATH=/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/arm-darwin-mono --aot=full,static,asmonly,nodebug,outfile=/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost.exe.s "/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/CurrentCost.exe"
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/bin/iPhone/Release/Effect.IPhone.app/CurrentCost.exe
Code: 126312 Info: 2658 Ex Info: 3158 Unwind Info: 2001 Class Info: 1899 PLT: 407 GOT Info: 8209 GOT Info Offsets: 3076 GOT: 3080 Offsets: 7236
Output file: '/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost.exe.s'.
Linking symbol: '_mono_aot_module_CurrentCost_info'.
Compiled 561 out of 561 methods (100%)
Methods without GOT slots: 314 (55%)
Direct calls: 77 (31%)
JIT time: 189 ms, Generation time: 100 ms, Assembly+Link time: 0 ms.
Generated /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/main.m
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Web.Services.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Web.Services.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/EffectCore.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/EffectCore.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/monotouch.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/monotouch.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CorePlotWrapper.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CorePlotWrapper.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/mscorlib.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/mscorlib.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Xml.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Xml.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Core.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Core.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost.exe.s -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost.exe.o 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/main.m -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/main.o 
/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/main.m: In function 'main':
/var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/main.m:1831: warning: implicit declaration of function 'chdir'
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Web.Services.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/EffectCore.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/monotouch.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CorePlotWrapper.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/mscorlib.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Xml.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Core.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost.exe.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/registrar.m -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/main.o -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -lz -u _catch_exception_raise -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/libs/iPhone -lCorePlot -force_load /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/libs/iPhone/libCorePlot.a
ld: ldr 12-bit displacement out of range (4344 max +/-4096) in _CATransform3DGetAffineTransform$stub in _CATransform3DGetAffineTransform$stub from /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.2 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Web.Services.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/EffectCore.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/monotouch.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CorePlotWrapper.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/mscorlib.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Xml.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/System.Core.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost.exe.o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/registrar.m -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/main.o -o /var/folders/kB/kBtPA5MIFKO6PNUFCu8T8U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp14340273.tmp/CurrentCost -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -lz -u _catch_exception_raise -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib -L/Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/libs/iPhone -lCorePlot -force_load /Users/mariotoffia/Projects/Effect/Project/Platform/iPhone/libs/iPhone/libCorePlot.a

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 3 warnings
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here.  Can you change your extra flags to:

-v -v -v -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone -lCorePlot -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/iPhone/libCorePlot.a"

Comment: Note the -v -v -s not inside -gcc_flags, but beside it.

Comment: Thanks geoff!!! :)
I've now have produced a more verbose output but I have to admit, I have no clue how to "fix" the "_CATransform3DGetAffineTransform$stub" 12-bit alignment error...

Comment: In desperation I've tried to remove all refs to CATransform3D (see Update II) - still getting same link error. And thanks again Geoff for your help! :)

Comment: Want to inject GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT = NO. Where do I do that? :)

Comment: I can solve this problem by setting sdk version to 3.2 and min os version 3.0 (I still have the -no_order_inits gcc flag). However this is very not desireable. Do anyone have a another solution?
 - Cheers/ Mario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have now is that your native library is a thumb library, and apples linker has issues linking thumb into larger projects.  You want to disable the thumb build for libCorePlot.a

You can find this setting in Xcode at Project->Edit Project Settings.  Search for "thumb" in All Configurations and uncheck the "Compile for Thumb" box.  Rebuild your native library, and you should be able to compile.

Comment: Thanks!! :) - I'll do that! - Do you know why it works when using iOS sdk 3.2 (minOsVer = "3.0")?

Answer (score 0):

As Geoff pointed out, I'm using coreplot is a thumbs library and thus re-compile with disabled thumbs build fixes the problem. If you don't want to do that and have the possibility to build using iOS SDK 3.2 (and set iphoneMinOsVersion to 3.0) it works for me anyway.

Cheers, 
 Mario